# Trigonometric equations: Finding the same solution for sin and cos

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, education

I am solving these trigonometric equations:

$-10.0317 = 10.0458 \times \sin(7.1726 \times 10^{-4} \times t)$

$-0.5319 = 10.0458 \times \cos(7.1726 \times 10^{-4} \times t)$

I solved the sin equation like:

$t = \frac{arcsin(\frac{-10.0317}{10.0458})}{7.1726 \times 10^{-4}} = -2116.119185$

$t = \frac{\pi - arcsin(\frac{-10.0317}{10.0458})}{7.1726 \times 10^{-4}} = 6496.110616$

I solved the cos equation like:

$t = \frac{arccos(\frac{-0.5319}{10.0458})}{7.1726 \times 10^{-4}} = 2263.849368$

$t = \frac{- \arccos(\frac{-10.0317}{10.0458})}{7.1726 \times 10^{-4}} = - 2263.849368$

None of cos or sin have any solution in common, but then we have the period

$p = \frac{2 \times \pi}{7.1726 \times 10^{-4}} = 8759.982861$

So both
$2263.849368$ and $6496.110616$ will be the solution but I can only have one solution for t so how do I know which one is correct. Also someone told me that the sin equation will be solved like:

$t = \frac{\pi - arcsin(\frac{-10.0317}{-10.0458})}{7.1726 \times 10^{-4}} = 2263.849368$

I have no I idea how they made the denominatior negative in the arcsin.

Comment: $\sin(x)=y \iff x=\arcsin(y)+2k\pi$ or $x=\pi-\arcsin(y)+2k\pi$ for some integer $k$.
$\cos(x)=y \iff x=\arccos(y)+2k\pi$ or $x=-\arccos(y)+2k\pi$ for some integer $k$.
Which one is correct? There are infinitely many solutions, none is more "correct".

Comment: Yes I know that but, in the question it states to give the value of t. Also is the last solution even correct?

Comment: Also the t goes in the formula sin(ω(x− t)) as a constant so wouldn't it not give different values for different t's? I mean t is supposed to be a constant here.

Comment: No, it's not. $\sin(\pi-x)=\sin(x)$ but $\sin(\pi+x)=-\sin(x)$.

Comment: And $\sin(\omega(x-t+2k\pi/\omega))=\sin(\omega(x-t))$, so it works for other values of $t$. There is not way to escape this, there are infinitely many solutions. Anyway, what's **exactly** the question? Are you supposed to find a $t$ such that both equations hold? Or to solve both equations separately?

Comment: I was supposed to use this function: $T(x) = c_1 + c_2t + c_3 \sin(ω(x − t))$ and could use this subsition $A_0 = c_3 \cos(ωt)$ and $A_1 = −c3 \sin(ωt)$. Anyways the question is very long but I found c3, A0, A1 as you can see but got stuck on t. The last term in the model represents the periodic variation of temperature over a year, where c3 is the amplitude, ω = 2π/(365 · 24) gives the period one year, and t is the phase shift (in hours). Btw T is the temperature and x is the time.